# Help diagnose bizzare MySQL query behavior

Tags: mysql

I have a very specific query that is acting up and I could use any help at all with debugging it.

There are 4 tables involved in this query.

**Transaction_Type**
Transaction_ID (primary)
Transaction_amount
Transaction_Type

**Transaction**
Transaction_ID (primary)
Timestamp

**Purchase**
Transaction_ID
Item_ID

**Item**
Item_ID
Client_ID

Lets say there is a transaction in which someone pays $20 in cash and $0 in credit it inserts two rows into the table.

```
//row 1
Transaction_ID: 1
Transaction_amount: 20.00
Transaction_type: cash
//row 2
Transaction_ID: 1
Transaction_amount: 0.00
Transaction_type: credit
```

here is the specific query:

```
SELECT 
 tt.Transaction_Amount, tt.Transaction_ID
FROM 
 ItemTracker_dbo.Transaction_Type tt
JOIN 
 ItemTracker_dbo.Transaction t
   ON
 tt.Transaction_ID = t.Transaction_ID
JOIN
 ItemTracker_dbo.Purchase p
   ON
 p.Transaction_ID = tt.Transaction_ID
JOIN
 ItemTracker_dbo.Item i
   ON
 i.Item_ID = p.Item_ID
WHERE
 t.TimeStamp >= "2010-01-06 00:00:00" AND t.TimeStamp <= "2010-01-06 23:59:59"
   AND
 tt.Transaction_Format IN ('cash', 'credit')
   AND
 i.Client_ID = 3
```

**when I execute this query, it returns 4 rows for a specific transaction. (it should be 2)**

When I remove ALL where clauses and insert WHERE tt.Transaction_ID = problematicID it only returns two.

EDIT:::::
 still repeats upon changing date range
    **The kicker:**

***When I change the initial daterange it only returns two rows for that specific transaction_id.***
::::

Is it the way I use join? that's all I can think of...

**EDIT: This is the problem**

in purchase - two sepparate purchase_ID's can have the same transaction_ID (purhcase_ID breaks down specific item sales).

**There are duplicate Transaction_ID rows in purchase_ID**

Comment: You need to post more information. To begin with, it would help if you posted the 4-row result you get from your query, the one you consider incorrect.

Comment: This is a typical "Select isn't broken" (http://lingpipe-blog.com/2007/06/27/select-isnt-broken-or-horses-not-zebras/) problem :)

Comment: ha.  Interesting read.  I apologize if my question read that I was blaming SELECT.  99.9999999% of the time it's the programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to see all the data in all the tables to be able to know where the problem is.  However, because the joins are the problem it is because one of your tables has two rows when you think it has only one.

Comment: Thanks - there are duplicate Transaction_ID rows in the purchase table.  This is how it is supposed to be.  I just need to come up with a different means to select the client_ID

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your schema.  You have rows with the same transaction_id, which is the primary key.  I would think they couldn't be marked primary in that database.  With two rows with the same id, that could cause unexpected extra rows to come back from the join(s).

Comment: He expects two rows returned.  It is the 4 rows that are bugging him.

Comment: Of course primary keys have to be unique, otherwise they're not keys. I think the answer here alludes that he doesn't have the right configuration for his tables, and perhaps hasn't configured which column(s) constitutes the primary key, and thus he has duplicates. And duplicates and joins will easily give you twice the number of rows you expected.